# What would a non-binary tā （他／她） look like?

Tags: characters

He and she in Mandarin looks like this:

Male tā: 他

Female tā: 她

**What would a non-binary tā look like?** 也?

它 is for animals and inanimate objects, not exactly fitting.

祂 is for gods, not really appropriate.

牠 is the same as 它.

---

For practicality purposes 你 could work the same:

male nǐ: 你

female nǐ: 妳

non-binary nǐ: 尔?

Comment: 你 is used for both male and female. 妳 is seldom used. There is no TA which can be used for both male and female (except when one does not know the gender, usually 他 is the default).

Comment: -：）） ‘He and see’ ？ 他， 见？ ‘

Comment: @fefe I believe 妳 is used much more frequently in Taiwan than on the mainland.

Comment: Fun fact : 佢 is come from Cantonese

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best candidate for a non-binary TA is in fact **他**. This is particularly obvious in the word **他們** (*them*), which definitely does not refer to a group of specifically males. 他 did not acquire the specific meaning **he** until well after **她** was invented, and 他 originally was a generic word meaning *other* (e.g. **他人** *the other person*).

她 did not actually exist before the [new culture movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Culture_Movement); its creation was from the direct influence from European languages. This is commonly seen in older popular novels like Dream of the Red Chamber, where 她 makes no appearances and it is incorrect to assume that 他 means **he** or **him**.

Note: In Taiwan, 他 is still sometimes used to refer to both he/him and she/her, although this practice is declining.

Answer (score 3):

TA (exactly what you see here in Pinyin, not in Chinese character) is widely used by media in China when the gender is not certain.  For example:

> [image: 孩子的眼睛需要你和TA共同守护]
>   孩子的眼睛需要你和TA共同守护
>   [news.youth.cn](http://news.youth.cn/sh/201910/t20191010_12090489.htm)

你 is good for both sexes in mainland China, in Taiwan and Hong Kong, some people like to change the left side to be a 女 if it refers to a female, but with too much exchange and communication with mainland, things have been changed.

Also in mainland, there is not a special word for the third person noun for God or deities or fairies.

Answer (score 3):

While not an official character, a recent article put forth the pronoun:

> [image: X也 drawn as a Chinese character]
> <sub>Cathy Lai, [‘X也’and ‘Ta’: The gradual rise of gender-neutral pronouns in Chinese](https://www.arianalife.com/topics/gender-equality/x%E4%B9%9Fand-ta-the-gradual-rise-of-gender-neutral-pronouns-in-chinese/), July 2020</sub>

It's typed "X也" since the character is not currently in use.

The article describes non-binary people also use 他 (acknowledging its history as non-gendered), 佢, and TA (the Latin letters).

Comment: Maybe it could be written: ⿰ﾒ也 (but that is using a Japanese glyph) perhaps: ⿰メ也 is better?